# Elasticsearch with retailer api

Tags: json, elasticsearch, e-commerce

I am new to elasticsearch. I'm building e-commerce website using retailer's APIs such as ASOS. I was wondering if it is possible to build elasticsearch on top of these api. Retailer APIs I'm using return json-like data which have product id, name and url etc.

It looks like when I query certain category of items, it returns poorly ordered product list. I would like to show well-ordered product list (depending on the search term) and also include auto-complete functionality trough elasticsearch.

I'm a bit confused with how I deploy this. Do I need to import json file to elasticsearch every time user search new item? or Do I need to build elasticsearch system with entire items returned from retailer api?

Apology if it's a naive question but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

You can query Elasticsearch on the data which is indexed.

Indexing the data every time a query comes is a bad idea. Then you will have so many steps to serve a query like - query ASOS, Index, Query

The best way is to index the entire data which is available in your retailerAPI if that is possible.